# VSC Autodocstring generation on enter doesn't work Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I installed the extension: autodocstring for Python and the snipped that genered the doc string after the ''' and "enter" doesn't work.

I restarted VSC and no change.

Here my settings.json:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "C:/Python/Python37-32",
"editor.hover.enabled": false,
"python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
"autoDocstring.docstringFormat": "google",
"autoDocstring.generateDocstringOnEnter": true,
```

}